# slideshow in javascript using a thread

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<img>` that I want to have alternate between 4 pictures using javascript. How can I go about doing this in a way that will still allow me to click on other parts of the page while the images are changing. Do I need a thread of some sort?

Comment: javascript does not have threads(except for webworker - html5). You need to look at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) / [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Comment: something like this: http://www.slidesjs.com/?